# Spring modelmapper map lazy loaded entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, modelmapper

I'm using modelmapper (http://modelmapper.org/) to map an entity with a lazy loaded list (by hibernate) of objects to a DTO with modelmapper.map().

The outcoming dto has a null value as list, although the entity's list is filled. When I'm changing to eager loading everything works fine, but my queries get too big, so that is not an option.

Does anyone know how modelmapper can map proxied hibernate entity classes?

This is my parent entity:

```
public class Category {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "category")
    @OrderBy("sortOrder")
    private SortedSet<CategorySubarea> categorySubareas;
}
```

The dto:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)
public class CategoryDto {

    private LinkedHashSet<@Valid CategorySubareaDto> categorySubareas;
}
```

This is how I use the mapper (sourceCategory being the entity and destinationCategory being the dto):

```
modelMapper.map(sourceCategory, destinationCategory);
```

of course something like this is working, but it is a very ugly workaround:

```
            sourceCategory.getCategorySubareas().forEach(subarea -> {
               // do nothing here
            });
            modelMapper.map(sourceCategory, destinationCategory);
```

Comment: Dont use modelmapper, use mapsturct. Modelmapper is very very slow. Also i reccomend you to skip lazy fields during dto mapping. Just use entity graphs to load what you really want.

Answer (score 0):

I know the good way to handle lazy/dto with mapstruct. Just create custom context class

```
public class CycleAvoidingMappingContext {

  private Map<Object, Object> knownInstances = new IdentityHashMap<Object, Object>();
  PersistenceUtil persistenceUnitUtil = Persistence.getPersistenceUtil();

  @SneakyThrows
  @BeforeMapping
  public <T> T getMappedInstance(Object source, @TargetType Class<T> targetType) {
    if (source != null) {
      for (PropertyDescriptor pd : Introspector.getBeanInfo(source.getClass()).getPropertyDescriptors()) {
        if (pd.getWriteMethod() != null && pd.getReadMethod() != null && !"class".equals(pd.getName())) {
          var vvalue = pd.getReadMethod().invoke(source);

          if (vvalue == null) {
            continue;
          }

          var classs = vvalue.getClass();
          if (HibernateProxy.class.isAssignableFrom(classs)) {
            try {
              if (Hibernate.isInitialized(vvalue) == false) {
                pd.getWriteMethod().invoke(source, null);
              }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return (T) knownInstances.get(source);
  }

  @BeforeMapping
  public void storeMappedInstance(Object source, @MappingTarget Object target) {
    knownInstances.put(source, target);
  }
}
```

And use it like that:

```
CrmClientMapper.INSTANCE.getDto(client, new CycleAvoidingMappingContext());
```

It will skip lazy fields, so you won't get lazy initialization exception and unnecessary queries to DB. Just you entity graphs for specifiying what relations you want to fetch.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I actually need the fields, so they should not be skipped

Comment: hob about using entity graph ?

Comment: never heard about it, but I'll look right into it. Many thanks :)

Comment: I think It may work like you want if you map to dto in transactional method, then modelmapper should fetch data, but i'm not sure

Comment: Also check if dto has setters

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the solution, I already use transactional and the dto has setters.

Comment: why do you typecast  destinationCategory to CategoryDto ? I think it could be a reason. modelmapper use getClass and what class it gets ? You should attach dto's code too

Comment: sorry, the casting was just for clarification. I updated the question and edited the dto

Comment: Do you check field values from response or debugger ?

Comment: both, and they are both null (with eager loading both is not empty)

Comment: Also it's strange that you use SortedSet in entity class, try to replace it with Set. Spring wraps entities with proxy and you can have problems if your lists aren't declared with interfaces (e.g spring can't wrap entity with proxy, so it can't lazy load relation). So problem can be in different scope,not mapper. Check if lazy loading works at all

Comment: it works, when I add the call to getCategoriesSubareas(), so I assume lazy loading works properly

Comment: Don't you have custom mapping configs (load lazy properties is normal behaviour for modelmapper, if you say that lazy relations are being fetched correctly in your code, but mapper can't fetch them it means that you either call mapping outside of transaction scope or have customized mapper that skip fields) ? If you use mapstruct you can see generated mapper classes, so it's simplify mapping problems debugging.